# IS there any changes in vespa installation?

Tags: vespa

We are facing some issues in Vespa installation on AWS EC2 centos instance, we are using the following steps for installation.

1. curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vespa-engine/sample-apps/master/aws_bootstrap.sh aws_bootstrap.sh
2. replace fqdn with instance ip
3. Create a hosts.txt with all instance ip's
4. for host in $(cat hosts.txt); do (ssh -i aws-dev-res.pem $host "sudo bash aws_bootstrap.sh master_ip" 2>&1 | tee /tmp/aws_bootstrap_$host.log) & done;   wait;   echo "Bootstrap done"

And while starting Vespa config server, we are getting below error-

> Will not start config server, host  is not part of VESPA_CONFIGSERVE.....

Please find the error in the attached screenshot.[image: Error image 1 with config server start]

[image: While installation]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The VESPA_CONFIGSERVERS environment variable should be populated with a comma separated list of hostnames. I expect this to work for you if you assign the list of FQDNs instead of IPs to VESPA_CONFIGSERVERS.